# Why doesn't sudo -S work for 'mysql' command?

Tags: sudo

I generally run `sudo mysql database < database.dump` and type the password on prompt.

In order to automate this, I tried to execute `echo 'password' | sudo -S mysql database < database.dump` but it is not recognizing my password.

I can `sudo -S` other commands normally. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: No you do not]

If you need to do something like this as root, please do it properly.

- Create a new script in `/usr/local/bin/` like `/usr/local/bin/my_mysql_task`. It'll need to be owned by root and `chmod +x`ed. The important thing here is that nobody but root can edit it.
- Then let your user run that script as root without a password by running `sudo visudo` and adding something like the following:

  ```
  username   ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/my_mysql_task
  ```

Now are you not only not piping your account password everywhere (in a way that would show in `ps` to most other users) but you're not piping at all, thus solving your core issue.

Never embed passwords. It's not necessary.

Comment: Nice solution. Just out of curiosity, do you know why my line was not working? Nice pic, btw.

Comment: I think Radu's probably on the right path but I'd wrap it a bit more completely: `echo "password" | sudo -S sh -c "mysql database < database.dump"` **Edit:** I can confirm that works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs because you use pipe and input redirection in the same command and in this case `sudo` try to read your password from `database.dump` file. The right way would be:

```bsh
mysql_cmd="mysql database < database.dump"
echo 'password' | sudo -S $mysql_cmd
```

or:

```bsh
alias mysql_cmd="mysql database < database.dump"
echo 'password' | sudo -S mysql_cmd
```

or, as [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) pointed in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365797/why-doesnt-sudo-s-work-for-mysql-command/365804#comment468043_365820):

```bsh
echo "password" | sudo -S sh -c "mysql database < database.dump"
```

Comment: something wrong with the line: `[sudo] password for user: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2  [...] `